# Mysqli query with zerofill

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello stackoverflow community, I need help with this mysqli query. My auto increase column in database is ZERO-FILL element for example 00001 so when I try to query like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."korteles 
    SET
    vardas = '".$this->clean_k_name."',
    pavard = ".$this->clean_k_surname.",
    WHERE korteles_nr = '00001'");
```

And I get error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE korteles_nr = 00001' at line 18

I was searching Internet for solving this problem. But can't find so please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be like this:-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."korteles 
    SET
    vardas = '$this->clean_k_name',
    pavard = '$this->clean_k_surname' 
    WHERE 
      korteles_nr = '00001'");
```

You have to remove the comma after `$this->clean_k_surname` variable